# Entity Framework AsSplitQuery feature does not work

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to use the new fancy split query feature `AsSplitQuery()`:

```
var result = await ctx.TObjects                    
                      .Include(o => o.ObjectPrototype)
                      .Include(o => o.ObjectIdentity)
                      .AsSplitQuery()
                      .ToListAsync(token);
```

But the generated SQL query is not split. What am I doing wrong? The sixth version of Entity Framework Core is used.

```
SELECT 
    t.id, t.md5, t.object_id, t.object_prototype, &etc
FROM
    t_objects AS t
LEFT JOIN 
    t_object_guids AS t0 ON t.object_prototype = t0.id
INNER JOIN 
    t_object_guids AS t1 ON t.object_id = t1.id
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong. But [split queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries) perform multiple queries *only* when including related *collections* because they are the ones which multiplicate "master" data records and cause "cartesian explosion" problem mentioned in the documentation link. Reference navigation properties have 0..1 cardinality, hence the data is returned as part of the "main" data record (just adding more columns).

So the split query result is achieved with 1 SQL query query for main entity and all included references, plus 1 SQL query for *each* included collection.

Your sample query includes only references, hence the result is 1 SQL query (no split).

Comment: Okay, we figured it out) But the split request pulls in data that should not be there. For example, the second request contains two extra joins and, accordingly, extra identifiers in the select. I skimmed through the documentation, but didn't figure out if there was a way to avoid this.

      SELECT t2.id, t2.object_id, t2.property_id, t2.value, t.id, t0.id, t1.id
      FROM t_objects AS t
      LEFT JOIN t_object_guids AS t0 ON t.object_prototype = t0.id
      INNER JOIN t_object_guids AS t1 ON t.object_id = t1.id
      INNER JOIN t_objects_properties AS t2 ON t.id = t2.object_id